# Can we have condition based filter

Tags: getstream-io

Can we have condition based filter e.g. suppose we have added "team:"ÜK"","game:"Cricket" for one feed and for other we have added "team:"ÜK"","game:"Football".

So can we get all the feed where team = uk and game = football

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply filters to feeds or retrieve data with a search queries. Instead, you should split the activities among specific feeds (eg. define a feed group for teams and one for games) and use `to` targeting field and follow relationships to send activities updates according to how you want to display the data.

This specific functionality is explained in the documentation as well: http://getstream.io/docs/#targetting